# Using CAShapeLayer to create UIActivityIndicator animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview, cashapelayer, caanimation

I want to create animation that looks like `UIActivityIndicator` animation using `CAShapeLayer` stroke.

I've create layer:

```
self.ovalShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

self.ovalShapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
self.ovalShapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
self.ovalShapeLayer.lineWidth = 15.0;

self.ovalShapeLayer.lineDashPattern = @[@1, @9];
self.ovalShapeLayer.lineDashPhase = 20.0;
self.ovalShapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
self.ovalShapeLayer.strokeStart = 0.0;
self.ovalShapeLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0;

self.ovalShapeLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.controlView.bounds].CGPath;

[self.controlView.layer addSublayer:self.ovalShapeLayer];
```

and it works very nice. I can also animate stroke end using

```
[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"]
```

But the `UIActivityIndicator` animation is more complex because it's dashes are fading in/out which looks like rotation. Do you have any ideas how to achieve that animation? I was thinking about creating each dash with a new `CAShapeLayer` and then use a `keyframe` opacity animation but it seems wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found wonderful class - `CAReplicatorLayer`.

Using that class I was able to create one `CALayer` object and replicate it using `CATransform3D`.

Here is my code:

```
    self.replicatorLayer = [CAReplicatorLayer layer];
    self.replicatorLayer.frame = self.controlView.bounds;
    [self.controlView.layer addSublayer:self.replicatorLayer];

    self.dashLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat dotSide = 4.0;

    self.dashLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.replicatorLayer.frame) - dotSide / 2, 0.0, dotSide, dotSide * 4);
    self.dashLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    self.dashLayer.cornerRadius = 1.5;
    self.dashLayer.cornerRadius = 2.5;
    [self.replicatorLayer addSublayer:self.dashLayer];

    self.replicatorLayer.instanceCount = 12;
    self.replicatorLayer.instanceTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI / 6, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    self.replicatorLayer.instanceDelay = 1.0 / 12;
```

and animation looks like this:

```
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.fromValue = @(1.0);
    animation.toValue = @(0.0);
    animation.duration = 1.0;
    animation.repeatCount = CGFLOAT_MAX;
    [self.dashLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can take 1 loader image as in attachment, and rotate that image on z-axis.

```
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * rotations * duration ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;

[imageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

[image]

```
@interface CustomView (){
    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *loaderImageView;
}

@end

@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
//        loaderImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){CGPointZero, 35, 35}];
//        loaderImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
//        [self addSubview:loaderImageView];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setUp{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation1;
    rotationAnimation1 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation1.toValue = @M_PI_2;
    rotationAnimation1.duration = 1.0;
    rotationAnimation1.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation1.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [loaderImageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation1 forKey:@"rotation"];
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: But in this method I'll need many UIImageView objects, am I right?

Comment: no, you will need only 1 image, and rotating the image on z axis will give output as in attached screenshot.

Comment: but I'm talking about the UIImageView, not UIImage. Shouldn't I have view for every dash?

Comment: [imageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"]; it is using uiimageview. set 1 image in uiimageview, and rotate it's layer as in shared code. It will work

Comment: Maybe I don't understand in correctly, but my view is rotation around it's own axis. Can you provide full code?

Answer (score 1):

I have spent much time to know how UIRefreshControl works, including UIActivityIndicator. Finally, I write a refresh control to avoid some issues in system refresh control. Here is the code of my activity indicator in refresh control: https://github.com/JohnWong/JWKit/blob/master/refresh-control/JWRefreshIndicatorView.m

If you use lldb to inspect system activity indicator and mine, you will find it is much the same as UIActivityIndicator. `CAReplicatorLayer` is the key to create the view.